# OpenCV: append different vectors as one row

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a `cv::Mat1f` vector which size is `kxd`. How can I fill it by appending `k` different `1xd` vectors?

I want to do something like:

```
    int k = 3, d = 3;
    cv::Mat1f testMat(1,k*d);
    for(int i=0; i<k;i++){
        cv::Mat1f partial(1,d,i);
        testMat.push_back(partial);
    }
```

Notice that the example above is much simpler that my real case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I don't know if it's the best one

```
    int k = 3, d = 3;
    cv::Mat1f testMat(1,k*d);
    for(int i=0; i<k;i++){
        cv::Mat1f partial(1,d,i);
        testMat.push_back(partial);
    }
    testMat = testMat.reshape(1,1);
```